# Unable to find explicit activity class have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: java, android, activity

Пробую  сделать recycling view, но столкнулась с такой ошибкой

> `    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find
>   explicit activity class
>   {student.wsiz.rzeszow.pl.myapplication/student.wsiz.rzeszow.pl.myapplication.StationAdapter};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Пробовала уже в манифесте объявить как

```
<activity android:name=".StationAdapter " />
```

и так

```
<activity android:name="student.wsiz.rzeszow.pl.myapplication.StationAdapter" />
```

И еще многими путями, которые нашла на сайте, но ничего не сработало. помогите пожалуйста

вот  сам манифест

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="student.wsiz.rzeszow.pl.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/unnamed"
        android:label="WSIiZ_Bus1"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Startowa"
            android:label="WSIiZ_Bus"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Sucharskiego" />
        <activity android:name=".Kielnarowo" />
        <activity android:name=".Tesco" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Menuu" />
        <activity android:name=".MPK" />
 <activity android:name=".StationAdapter " />




        <activity
            android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

А  вот тот самый адаптер через который орет

```
    package student.wsiz.rzeszow.pl.myapplication;


public class StationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SetViewHolder> {
   private Activity activity ;
   List<Item> items = Collections.emptyList();
   private OnTapListener onTapListener;

  public StationAdapter(Activity activity, List<Item> items){

      this.activity = activity;
      this.items = items;
  }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SetViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent , int viewType) {
      View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item,parent,false);
      return new SetViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SetViewHolder holder, final int position) {
      holder.txt_stations.setText(items.get(position).getStation());
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
if (onTapListener != null){
    onTapListener.OnTapView(position);
}
    }
});
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }
    public void setOnTapListener(OnTapListener onTapListener){
      this.onTapListener = onTapListener;
    }
}
```

---

Вот сам фрагмент

```
   public class StationFragment extends Fragment  {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private ArrayList<Item> arrayList= new ArrayList<Item>();
    private Cursor cursor;
    private StationAdapter adapter;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup= (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,container,false);
        recyclerView= (RecyclerView) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        loadDatabase();
        return viewGroup;
    }
public void loadDatabase(){
        databaseHelper= new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        try {
            databaseHelper.checkDataBase();
            databaseHelper.openDataBase();
        } catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            cursor = databaseHelper.Query("select * from myrasp");
            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        Item item = new Item();
                        item.setStation(cursor.getString(2));
                        arrayList.add(item);

                    }
                    while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        adapter= new StationAdapter(getActivity(),arrayList);
        adapter.setOnTapListener(new OnTapListener() {
            @Override
            public void OnTapView(int position) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Click to " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

Comment: Можете приложить код, откуда вы вызываете активити, в котором ваш фрагмент с RecyclerView?

Comment: Добавила в вопрос код.

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вы в манифесте прописываете класс вашего адаптера? Нужно прописывать класс вашего активити, наследника Activity или AppCompatActivity, в котором ваш RecyclerView.

Comment: Дело в том что мой RecyclerView  он в фрагменте и наследство там по фрагмент.

Comment: уберите упоминанием адаптера из манифеста